# GIF files are not animated in the Swiper slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I need gifs to be animated always. When the page loads, the gif animates for the first second, and then stops. In order for it to start, I have to press the left mouse button.
When I remove the cursor from the image, it becomes inactive again.
What can be done to make gifs animated? What are the ways to solve this problem.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        effect: 'cube',
        grabCursor: true, 
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        
        cubeEffect: {
           shadow: true,
           slideShadows: true,
           shadowOffset: 50,
           shadowScale: 0.3,
           centerSlidesBounds: true,
        },

        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: true,

        
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',

        },

        });
```

```css
.main {
  position: absolute;
  //padding: 16px;
  //margin-top:60px;
  width: 50%; 
}


.swiper-button-prev{
left:  2%;
}

.swiper-button-next{
left:  92%;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -25%;
  position: relative;
}

.left-element {
    background: silver;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 0;
}
h1.left-element {
width: 80%;
height: 90%
}

 img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Gif</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
</head>

<body>
   <div class="main">
   <h1 class="left-element">12345</h1>
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBv4T.gif"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide">
           <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBv4T.gif"></a> 
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBv4T.gif"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBv4T.gif"></a>
        </div>

     </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see that it works perfectly on Chrome. I found this issue in Mozilla. Can you specify?

Comment: Checked on the browser firefox.

Comment: In "Opera" and "Chrome" it works as it should.